# Using CDK to build IAM Role for lambda function

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I have the following role written for my lambda application. I want to translate it to CDK in typescript.

```
  LambdaRole:
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement:
    - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
    Version: '2012-10-17'
  Policies:
  #CloudWatch permissions to publish logs
  - PolicyName: 'cloudWatchPolicy'
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Action: ['logs:CreateLogGroup', 'logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:PutLogEvents']
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: '*'
      Version: '2012-10-17'
  #DynamoDB permissions permissions to get/query item
  - PolicyName: 'dynamoDBPolicy'
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Action:
            - dynamodb:GetItem
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: '*'
      Version: '2012-10-17'
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
```

How can I replicate this role in typescript?

Comment: Do you have *any* experience with CDK? Then it should not be a problem to translate that. If you have no experience with CDK then follow some tutorials and get some experience at which point the translation will not longer be a problem.

Comment: I know how to add inline poilicies and managed roles.I have written the role but I am confused about the AssumeRolePolicyDocument part.

Comment: In what way? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.CfnRole.html#assumerolepolicydocument

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to add permissions to a lambda function in cdk. But if for some reason you want to create a role and use that role to lambda, you can do like below.

```
// Create a Role with service Pricipal Lambda
const tenantUserRole = new iam.Role(this, "TenantUserRole", {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
});

// Create a Lambda and pass the role
const myLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "my-lambda", {
  code: new lambda.InlineCode(`
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('event',event)
    callback(null,'10')
  }
    `),
  handler: "index.handler",
  role: tenantUserRole,
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
});

// Attach Inline Polices to role
tenantUserRole.attachInlinePolicy(
  new iam.Policy(this, "my-inline", {
    statements: [
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["dynamodb:GetItem"],
        resources: ["*"],
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

Other way is not to create a role , but simply attach policies to role created by Lambda construct.

```
// Create a Lambda without passing a role, Function construct will create a role and attaches managed policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
const myLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "my-lambda", {
  code: new lambda.InlineCode(`
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('event',event)
    callback(null,'10')
  }
    `),
  handler: "index.handler",
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
});

// Attach Inline Polices to role created by lambda in previous step.
myLambda.role!.attachInlinePolicy(
  new iam.Policy(this, "my-inline", {
    statements: [
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["dynamodb:GetItem"],
        resources: ["*"],
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

Comment: there is no sts:assume role in this

Comment: @mightyMouse Both these code blocks will create a role with principal `lambda.amazonaws.com`. First block we are specifying `new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com")` , second code block, Lamba construct will create it for us.